# How to align button to bottom with Java

Tags: java, android

I cannot get the button to align at the bottom of the screen with `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM` how can I get it to position correctly at the bottom of the screen?

Also, how I can create a margin, for example, 10 pixels from the bottom of the screen? I don't see an option to be able to add a positional offset anywhere in the layout rules.

```
RelativeLayout gameLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
Button gameButton = new Button(this);
gameButton.setText("Start");
gameButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
gameLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
//gameButton.
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonDetails = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
buttonDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
buttonDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM);

gameLayout.addView(gameButton, buttonDetails);
setContentView(gameLayout);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM` instead of `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM`. To set margins please use `setMargins()` method.

```
buttonDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
buttonDetails.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 10);
```